# as3 adding commas to dynamic text numbers on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, actionscript, numbers

So I have a dynamic text field on stage (stage_clickCounter) where every time I click on said button the variable clickCounter goes up by 1.

I'm using this piece of code to display the numbers on screen:

```
stage_clickCounter.text = numberOfClicks.toString();
```

The numbers show up fine and all, but once I get to 1,000 clicks it shows up without the comma

```
1000//shows this on dynamic text field
1,000//would much rather prefer this
```

How can I do this? I have numbers and punctuations embedded into the font already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For positive integers:

```
function addComma(num:uint):String{
    if(num == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    var str:String="";
    while(num>0){
        var tmp:uint=num%1000;
        str=(num>999?","+(tmp<100?(tmp<10?"00":"0"):""):"")+tmp+str;
        num=num/1000;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Usage:

```
trace(addComma(1000999333)); //output:1,000,999,333
```

**Edit:**

For negative and positive integers:

```
function addComma(num:int):String{
    if(num == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    var str:String="";
    var sign:String=num>0?"":"-";
    num=Math.abs(num);
    while(num>0){
        var tmp:int=num%1000;
        str=(num>999?","+(tmp<100?(tmp<10?"00":"0"):""):"")+tmp+str;
        num=num/1000;
    }
    return sign+str;
}
```

Comment: Super duper rad. Thanks mate. The way I made it work was like this.

stage_clickCounter.text = addComma(numberOfClicks).toString();

Comment: Note that you don't need .toString(); at the end since addComa alredy returns a string :)

Comment: So this has brought up another problem methinks. After I reach 2,000,000,000 the number disappears for a bit and then comes back, but with a different number

I click to add 500,000,000. After I get to 2,000,000,000 the next few clicks are empty. Then "205,032,704" pops up. Clicking again adds the proper 500m and bumps it to "705,032,704" Do you guys know exactly what is happening?

Also, thanks mika! Fixed it. :)

Comment: @prpl, int's max value is 2147483647, try change int variables to uint(max value=4294967295)

Comment: There's a built-in library class, NumberFormatter, to do this for you, and it supports localization...

Answer (score 2):

Adobe has a NumberFormatter class just for this purpose. It even support localization. From http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS9b644acd4ebe59998b99a90125fc4fecfb-7ffb.html

```
var nf:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(LocaleID.DEFAULT); 
trace(nf.formatNumber(-123456.789));
//Output: -123,456.789
```

Most modern programming languages should include some type of support for formatting numeric strings. You should only be coding your own implementation if there is a serious reason not to use the built-in library.

Comment: Actually the flash implementation of Number formatter is not consistent across devices even when you specify a locale since it relies on the users own operating systems implementation, so anyone who wants consistency might have a pretty good reason for writing their own.

"different users can see different formatting results, even when using the same locale ID." - [source](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/NumberFormatter.html)

Comment: @Nate914375  It's important to get new programmers used to looking for and using standard libraries, rather than coding their own solutions from scratch for everything. Some of the worst code bases I've ever worked with are those where the programmer didn't know to look for built-in functions and rolled their own buggy solution for everything.

Comment: Most people don't need to reinvent the wheel.